# SQL Query on sum (CASE, WHEN, ELSE)

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a report for all loans by branch but the results i get when i run the script does not give me the correct figure. Was wondering if i can get help on if I am writing the codes the wrong way.

There is a column which has different products lines including deposit and loans but i want my report for just loans. and i would like it in the format below;

Branch code, branch name, region name, directorate name, loan volume

```
    SELECT a.banchcode, 
       a.branchname, 
       b.regionname, 
       b.directoratename, 
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN a.caption IN('BUSINESS  LOAN', 'OVERDRAFTS', 'OVERDRAFTS', 'RETAIL PRODUCT LOAN', 
            'RETAIL PRODUCT LOAN', 'TERM LOANS', 'CBN/BOILOAN', 'LEASES', 'CREDIT CARD', 'LEASES', 'CREDIT CARD', 'CREDIT CARD - FCY',
            'ASSET ACQUISITION SCHEME', 'TERM LOANS - FCY', 'DEVICE LOAN SCHEME')
               THEN a.previousmonthaveragevolume
               ELSE 0
           END) June_Loan
FROM bs_report a
     LEFT JOIN mpr_team_structure b ON a.banchcode = b.branch_code
WHERE a.period = '7'
GROUP BY a.banchcode, 
         a.branchname, 
         b.regionname, 
         b.directoratename;
```

The figures i get for each branch is not correct and higher than what is expected.

Comment: Can you add some sample data from both table with your expected output?

Comment: might be due to your left join. If you have records in table a with no match in table b you could get higher numbers than you may be expecting. Try using an Inner Join and see if that helps.

Comment: It seems your table "mpr_team_structure" has multiple records for one or more Key reference value which is causing increment of row. As a result you are getting higher values then you expectation.

Comment: create a master table for caption and apply the left join with bs_report